# Creating standalone executable for python application with config and output files

Tags: python, configuration, compilation, executable

I've created a python application for scraping local publications and identifying articles that contain certain keywords. Within the main application directory are contained a main script and several custom modules, which are imported by the main script. Also contained in this directory are sub-directories for configuration files, logging files, and output files. The configuration files (publications, keywords) and the output files (identified articles) must be accessible and editable by the user.

I would like to distribute this application such that users would not need to download python and the requisite dependencies. It seems to me that the best method for this is to create a standalone executable with a utility such as pyinstaller. However, I don't know how to do so while also retaining the configuration and output files as accessible and editable, as mentioned above. Any suggestions, including other methods of application design/distribution, are appreciated.

Comment: Would sending people a folder be okay?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller in collaboration with NSIS to create an installer that transports zipped folders. This zipped folder can (and must) contain your newly created script.exe and all of its required dependencies. They would be accessible to the user as they will simply receive the entire folder. This video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4